# MobX with Victory Charts, update chart with store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I want to update the Candlestickchart inside index.js with the chartData in chartStore.js. So far, the chart is an empty object. The code is short and basic.

If I paste the chart data into index.js, the chart renders.

An empty space is rendered instead of a chart. Here is the output from MobX Developer Tools:

[image]

--- chartStore.js ---

```
import { action, observable } from 'mobx';

class ChartStore {
  @observable chartData = [
    {open: 5, close: 10, high: 15, low: 0},
    {open: 10, close: 15, high: 20, low: 5},
    {open: 15, close: 20, high: 22, low: 10},
    {open: 20, close: 10, high: 25, low: 7},
    {open: 10, close: 8, high: 15, low: 5}
  ]

  constructor(rootStore) {
    this.rootStore = rootStore;
  }

}

export default ChartStore;
```

--- index.js ---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import { VictoryCandlestick } from 'victory';

class CandlestickChart extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Chart</h1>
        <VictoryCandlestick
          data={this.props.chartStore.chartData}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default compose(
  inject('chartStore'),
  observer
)(CandlestickChart);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the answer. Just add .slice() to this ...

```
    <VictoryCandlestick
      data={ this.props.chartStore.chartData.slice() }
    />
```